# Can I can control an RC servo using only a 5VDC and GND signal?

Tags: servo

I'm working on an application where I want a servo to open and close a hatch. Because I only need the servo to operate in two positions, I'm curious if I can forgo the PWM aspect and just supply a 5VDC and GND signal to toggle between two positions.

Comment: I would hook up 5V power to the device as normal, but then I would use a 5V GPIO output in place of the PWM signal.

Comment: you could just use a 555 timer to generate the control signal ... there is a servo tester available on the web somewhere

Comment: https://www.instructables.com/id/Drive-Servos-with-a-555-timer-IC/

Comment: A digital servo *might* behave the way you want. Or it might completely not. It's totally up to the way they made it as an after though. There's a total possibility it could just go into fail-safe mode instead.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I doubt that it would work the way you want. In most analog servos, the input pulses trigger an internal multivibrator that's controlled by the feedback pot, and the resulting pulse is combined using some simple logic with the original pulse to drive the motor H-bridge — the difference in pulse widths drives the motor one way or the other until they are equal.

If you don't provide a stream of pulses, the motor drive will never get activated.

Why not just use a regular DC motor along with some limit switches?

Comment: +1 For the alternative solution

Comment: Buying a read to go servo would be much simpler and cheaper than coming up with a DC motor with limit switch design in my opinion.

Comment: @Izzo: Even if you use the motor and gear train from a server [as mguima suggested](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/a/504320/11683), you still need to add the limit switches. Or you can just go ahead and generate the PWM with your GPIO pin.

Answer (score 2):

No, you need to feed the servo pulses or it will not move. Typically they hold the last position if you don't give a signal.

You could give it pulses indicating the desired position for sufficient time for the servo to position, then stop. From a GPIO that could be done with simple delay functions rather than PWM hardware. The time to move the full travel will be listed on the servo datasheet.

Thanks to @BruceAbbott for the comment that the servos usually require the position pulses to be sustained during positioning.

Comment: Generally you have to give it pulses for long enough to move to the desired position. Standard servos usually take ~300ms to go 90º, which is ~15 pulses. https://servodatabase.com/

Answer (score 1):

*I'm working on an application where I want a servo to open and close a hatch. Because I only need the servo to operate in two positions, I'm curious if I can forgo the PWM aspect and just supply a 5VDC and GND signal to toggle between two positions.*

If all that you need is a DC motor that opens and closes a hatch, there's a thing that can be done - but, strictly, it will not be a "servo" anymore, because it will not be PWM controlled.

Open the servo case and cut out the circuit board that controls the servo mechanism, take out the potentiometer which is the position sensor of the servo, and then connect the wires directly to the motor.

Now, it's just a DC motor in a servo case, still with the gears. Maybe you will need to use a x-acto knife or a file to remove a little notch that there is in one of the gears, and prevents that gear to complete a full turn.

[image]

Of course you will need to use a proper control to the motor, since will not stop at the end or course (specially if you remove the notch).

This servo mod is a common "trick" of makers when building the "useless machine", a box with just a mecanical switch in its top; you turn the switch on, and the device turns the motor on, and the motor protudes a "finger" from inside the box, which turn the switch off. You can find a lot of sites and blog posts with good instructions on modifying the servo, e.g., take a look at the item 3 in [this link](https://www.instructables.com/id/Useless-Machine-Instructions/), that's where from I copied the image above.